# Error 500 while changing order status on Prestashop 1.6

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm getting error 500 while changing the status of one order in the Prestashop 1.6 backoffice. However, when I set _PS_MODE_DEV_ to true it starts working without any error! Any hint?

Comment: Your php settings displays the errors?

Comment: No errors registered @sarcom

Comment: May be the error occurred on changing order status first time only. Try changing status of fresh order after enabling developer mode and share the error in this question.